# How to mirror a MySQL database using just one server

Tags: mysql, replication

I need to frequently duplicate one database on my MySQL server to a mirror database on the same MySQL server.

I am writing a bash script that makes a mirror of my web application (PHP/MySQL) on a separate subdomain. Users can use this mirror to try out all kinds of crazy things without affecting the production environment. The script is supposed to run automatically every night.

Duplicating the source code is easy. I just use `rsync -a` to copy everything from the directory holding the production environment to the mirror directory and apply a patch to update a few configuration files. The problem is with duplicating the database, which has grown to nearly 3 GB in size.

When I use `mysqldump live_db | mysql mirror_db` then it takes forever to duplicate the database. Also, during that time CPU usage peaks to 100% and my web application becomes unusably slow.

Database replication does not seem to be an option since I only have one MySQL server. Replication requires two servers.

What is the best way to duplicate the production database? It doesn't have to be fast, but it should not impact performance of the system too much. People should still be able to use my web application while the mirror script is running in the background.

Comment: Would it be possible in your scenario to run a second mysql server instance on the same server?

Comment: In theory that could work VolkerK, but that would be a real big hassle to set up. Turning a spare desktop machine into a second server would be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions I can think of:

1) Buy a faster server

2) Copy the raw tables. This isn't ideal but if it's just for testing could be viable.

I'm going to assume you're using MyISAM tables but here are the steps:

- Ideally write lock the tables in the production database, ignore if this is not possible
- Copy the binary table data/indexes from `/var/lib/mysql/production_schema` (or similar) to `/var/lib/mysql/development_schema`. `rsync -a` (run as root) would be idea for doing this with.
- restart the MySQL server (this is your only downtime in the whole process)
- `CHECK/REPAIR` all of the tabes in `development_schema`

It's worth adding that I wouldn't use this method as a way of copying data from one production environment to another without stopping the server before making the copy.

3) consider whether you need all of the production data in the development environment. Could you be smart and only copy a subset of the data?

Comment: It's a dual core AMD64 with 2 GB RAM. Not exactly a slow server. Unfortunately I do need all the data mirrored. One of the things we test on the mirror instance are upgrades of the web application. I used to test with sample data and partial data, but always ran into problems upgrading the full database when upgrading just the partial data worked. So now we test upgrades with the full production dataset.

Comment: Rsyncing the raw tables works like a charm and the production website remains responsive throughout. I realise that there is the possibility or errors/corruption while copying for for my testing purposes this suffices.

Comment: Glad it works!

Be sure to always run CHECK/REPAIR on the tables in case you end up with corrupted tables on copy (this could easily happen if something writes to the table in the middle of you copying it)

Answer (score 0):

If you have MyISAM tables, you could use [mysqlhotcopy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlhotcopy.html).

Comment: Hot Backup is an option for InnoDB tables, if you're willing to drop some cash: http://www.innodb.com/products/hot-backup/order/

Comment: For myisam, it still read-locks the tables while the copy happens, which usually will cause downtime.